# TikZ 3.0: Colorate a specific node in a subgraph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this complete subgraph:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard, graphdrawing}

\begin{document}

\tikz[nodes={draw, circle}]
  \graph { subgraph K_n[n=5, radius=1.5cm, clockwise]; };

\end{document}
```

[image: K_5]

And now I want to colorate node number 3 in gray. How do I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simpler solution might be to manually create nodes with desired attributes in `clockwise` order before using the `subgraph` command.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\graph [nodes={draw, circle}, n=5, radius=1.5cm, clockwise]
{ 1; 2; 3[fill=gray]; 4; 5; subgraph K_n };
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm always looking for simple solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Less straightforward than I had anticipated. Firstly, I reimplement the `subgraph I_n` graph macro from `tikzlibrarygraphs.standard.code.tex` to allow a style to be applied according to the number of the node.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,graphdrawing}
\begin{document}
\tikzgraphsset{declare={subgraph I_n}{%
  \foreach \n in \tikzgraphV{ \n[/tikz/node \n/.try] }
}}
\tikz[nodes={draw, circle}, node 3/.style={fill=gray}]
  \graph { subgraph K_n[n=5, radius=1.5cm, clockwise]; };
\end{document}
```

[image]

Secondly, one can combine parts of this approach with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269297/23215) answer (which would become a bit unwieldy with large n) as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,graphdrawing}
\begin{document}
\tikz[nodes={draw, circle}, node 3/.style={fill=gray}] 
  \graph [n=5, radius=1.5cm, clockwise]{ 
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}{ \i[/tikz/node \i/.try] }; subgraph K_n; };
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Answer (score 8):

The following example puts the gray background for node 3 in the background layer:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard, graphdrawing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, circle}]
  \graph {
    subgraph K_n[n=5, radius=1.5cm, clockwise];
  };
  \scoped[on background layer]
    \node[circle, fill=gray, draw=none] at (3) {\phantom{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I believe that you doubled the edge from node 3. It works, but it is not optimal.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic There is no duplicated edge. Only the node at the place of 3 is duplicated. The first time on the background it is drawn with `fill=gray` and empty text (`\phantom{3}`), then the drawn node from the graph follows on top.

Comment: By "edge" I ment the circle around node number 3, which is doubled. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic The drawing on the background can be disabled by `draw=none`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

I define a style that target a specific vertex. It can be used like this :

```
vertex={3}{fill=yellow}
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to recover the vertex number (at this moment `\tikz@fig@name` seems to be not yet defined), so I use a new counter.

```
\documentclass[border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard, graphdrawing}
\newcounter{nodenum}\setcounter{nodenum}{0}
\tikzset{
  step counter/.code={\stepcounter{nodenum}},
  vertex/.code 2 args={
    \ifnum\thenodenum=#1\pgfkeysalso{#2}\fi}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, circle,
    step counter,vertex={3}{fill=yellow},vertex={4}{thick,red}}]
    \graph {
      subgraph K_n[n=5, radius=1.5cm, clockwise];
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT :** Actually we can use `\tikz@lib@graph@name` in place of custom counter :

```
\documentclass[border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard, graphdrawing}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{vertex/.code 2 args={\ifnum\tikz@lib@graph@name=#1\pgfkeysalso{#2}\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, circle, vertex={3}{fill=yellow}, vertex={4}{thick,red}}]
    \graph {
      subgraph K_n[n=5, radius=1.5cm, clockwise];
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```