# Custom labelling of nodes in a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphs

I have this complete subgraph:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={draw, circle}, n=5, clockwise, radius=2cm]
  { subgraph K_n; };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I wish to somehow distinguish vertex number 3, I can consult [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269272/tikz-3-0-colorate-a-specific-node-in-a-subgraph)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={draw, circle}, n=5, clockwise, radius=2cm]
  { 1; 2; 3[fill=gray]; 4; 5; subgraph K_n; };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now, suppose that instead of highlighting it, I wish to change it contents. For example, suppose I wish to change its label to the greek letter alpha, instead of the current 3. Something like this will not work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={draw, circle}, n=5, clockwise, radius=2cm]
  { 1; 2; 3[contents=$\alpha$]; 4; 5; subgraph K_n; };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any other way to achieve this fairly simple task, or, in general, label the vertices of K_n in a custom way? Of course, I can manually draw K_5 and label the nodes, but tikz `graphs.standard` library is nice and I wish to use it in order to avoid manual calculations.

## Update

I have a found a way to label vertex 3 with a different number.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={draw, circle}, n=5, clockwise, radius=2cm]
  { subgraph K_n [V={1,2,7,4,5}];};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This also works if instead of `7` I write `a` or `FOO` (in the last case it makes the node a bit larger). I can even put there `7/2`.

What I can't put there instead of `7` is `7,2` (even inside `{...}`) or `\alpha` or `$\alpha$` or `{$\alpha$}`. Trying any of these simply destroy the graph.

Comment: Please complete your code so we can copy-paste-compile it rather than having to guess the packages and libraries you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this helps or not. It does not use the `subgraph K_n` but instead specifies the nodes manually so that their contents can be specified as desired. `clique` is used to draw the connections automatically, partially emulating the functionality provided by the `subgraph`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={draw, circle}, clique, n=5, clockwise, radius=2cm]
  {
    1/"$\alpha$", 2/"7,2", 3/"$x^2$", 4/"9,8,4", 5/"$\zeta$"
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: alternate names in circle]

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot. it's real helpful suggestion. I found it also works by simple node chains in a `graph`. So I guess it works in whole `graph` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs}
\begin{document}

\tikz 
\graph [
1/.style={ minimum size=10pt, draw, circle},
0/.style={empty nodes},
]
{
""      -!-06[0]-!-07[0]-!-08[0];
""      -!-16/"1"[1]->17/"2"[1]->18/"3"[1]->"y(n+3)";
"u(n+3)"-!-25/"1"[1]->26/"2"[1]->27/"3"[1]->"y(n+2)";
"u(n+2)"-!-34/"1"[1]->35/"2"[1]->36/"3"[1]->"y(n+1)";
"u(n+1)"-!-43/"1"[1]->44/"2"[1]->45/"3"[1]->"y(n)";
"u(n)"  -!-52/"1"[1]->53/"2"[1]->54/"3"[1]->"y(n-1)";
"u(n-1)"-!-61/"1"[1]->62/"2"[1]->63/"3"[1]->"y(n-2)";

"u(n-2)"-!-b0-!-b1-!-b2;
b0->[dotted]62->54;
b1->[dotted]63;
"u(n-2)"->[dotted]61->53->45;"u(n-1)"->52->44->36;"u(n)"->43->35->27;"u(n+1)"->34->26->18;"u(n+2)"->25->17;

b0          ->61->52->43->34->25->16->[dotted]06;
b1          ->62->53->44->35->26->17->[dotted]07;
b2          ->63->54->45->36->27->18->[dotted]08;
};
\end{document}
```

[image]