# labelling vertex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am new here. I think this is the right place to ask a question about labeling in vertex. I want to label vertex on complete graph 12 node by using TikZ. I use the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph { subgraph K_n [n=12, clockwise, radius=2cm] };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to label the vertices with even numbers between 0 and 22, i.e. that they will contain numbers 0, 2, 4, ... ,22.  How should I do that?

(Edit is based on OP clarification in his comment below)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is the problem? Your vertices are numbered (from 1 to 12). If you like to have border around it, than write: `\graph[nodes={draw, circle}]
          {subgraph K_n [n=12, clockwise, radius=4cm]};`

Comment: thank's for your attention but I still don't get what I need. maybe my writing is quite bad. exactly I want to label vertices start from 0 to 22 using only even numbers.

Comment: As far as I can see, no one answers to question, to which you mark that this is duplicate, answer OP question. The closest to OP problem is, to my opinion, the @cfr answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277087/custom-labelling-of-nodes-in-a-graph.

Comment: See if my edit of your question is correct and please confirm, if the answers, to which your question should be duplicate solve your problem.

Comment: I have get what I mean by using this command

Comment: \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={draw, circle}, clique, n=12, clockwise, radius=2cm]
  {
    1/"0", 2/"2", 3/"4", 4/"6", 5/"8", 6/"10", 7/"12", 8/"14", 9/"16", 10/"18", 11/"20", 12/"22", subgraph K_n;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: thank's a lot to all of you especially to Zarko who gave this link and learn from it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277087/custom-labelling-of-nodes-in-a-graph

Comment: Link to duplicate question is wrong. It not solve OP problem. Correct link are give in my and in OP comment. People, who close this question, please correct this misleading information.