# Tikz, issue with applying style to nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs

I am a beginner in LaTeX, especially in Ti*k*Z package.

I want to draw Peterson graph with some styles.

My code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\usetikzlibrary[graphs]

\tikzset{   
    every node/.style={draw, circle, very thick},
    mark/.style={fill=black!50, circle},    
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \graph [simple, edges={thick}, clockwise] {
                subgraph C_n [n=5, name=A, radius=2cm]; 
                subgraph I_n [V={a,b,c,d,e}, name=B, radius=1cm];           

                (A 5)[mark] --[red] (A 4)[mark],
                A 1 -- B a,
                A 2 -- B b,
                A 3 -- B c,
                A 4 -- B d,
                A 5 -- B e,
                B a -- B c,
                B a -- B d,
                B b -- B e,
                B b -- B d,
                B e -- B c
            };

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

I expect, that nodes 4 and 5 will be gray, but I have only red edge.

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: your code is not compileable !

Comment: \tikzset be before \begin{document}, and \begin{tikzpicture}[] in right place.

Comment: Modify your question by clicking on the `edit` button.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a bug in the `graphs.standard` library, I tried in vain to apply a style to the graphs in this library. It does not work. Let's wait and see what other TikZ users think about it.

Comment: You can not change the color of existing node. The node (A 5) is created in the `subgraph` command before you try to apply `[mark]` to it. Check [TikZ 3.0: Colorate a specific node in a subgraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269272).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the link given by @Kpym in his commentary and adapted the [solution given by hftf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269297/138900).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}


\tikzset{   
    every node/.style={draw, circle, very thick},
    marko/.style={fill=cyan!50, circle},    
}

\begin{document}
 %   \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \graph [simple, edges={thick},n=5,radius=2cm, clockwise] {
            1;2;3;4[marko];5[marko];
                subgraph C_n [n=5, name=A, radius=2cm]; 
                subgraph I_n [V={a,b,c,d,e}, name=B, radius=1cm];           

                (A 5) --[blue] (A 4),
                A 1 -- B a,
                A 2 -- B b,
                A 3 -- B c,
                A 4 -- B d,
                A 5 -- B e,
                B a -- B c,
                B a -- B d,
                B b -- B e,
                B b -- B d,
                B e -- B c
            };

        \end{tikzpicture}
%        
%        \tikz
%\graph [nodes={draw, circle}, n=5, radius=1.5cm, clockwise]
%{ 1; 2; 3[fill=gray]; 4; 5; subgraph K_n };
  %  \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]