# TikZ, \graph, Fail to Change the Color

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I do not understand why the style of a node does not change. The color of node 6 does not change, how can I achieve this? It seems after a node is created the style cannot be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ graphs, graphs.standard }
\usetikzlibrary{ calc }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph [nodes={fill = blue}, empty nodes] {
            subgraph I_n [clockwise, radius = 2cm, n = 6];
            6 [fill = red];
            7 [at = { ($(1) ! 0.5 ! (4)$) }, fill = red];
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several approaches are described in the answer to this question: [TikZ 3.0: Colorate a specific node in a subgraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269272/tikz-3-0-colorate-a-specific-node-in-a-subgraph). Here is one possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269274/    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ graphs, graphs.standard,backgrounds }
\usetikzlibrary{ calc }

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph [nodes={fill = blue}, empty nodes] {
            subgraph I_n [clockwise, radius = 2cm, n = 6];
            };
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}    
            \node[fill = red] at (6) {};
            \node[fill = red] at ($(1) ! 0.5 ! (4)$) {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]